# Simple WCF SSL Web Service

Tags: wcf, ssl, x509

I'm creating a WCF web service on my machine, first service of this type on this box.
I already have a .NET 2.0 enterprise app that runs on my box running a lot of SOA SSL services.

I have an internal SSL Server Authority that has created a SSL x509 cert for my computer. I also have a lot of client certificates created by the same certificate authority that are used for testing. All these certificates work with my current app.

I'm writing a WCF SSL webservice to accept a plain XML message, and for now, spit out every HTTPHeader that exists for each request.

I'm having some issues setting the thing up. I have it working find without SSL.

When I consume the WCF service (https) it downloads and creates the objects and modifies the app.config normally, it prompts me about the server certificate as well. But, when I send a message to that WCF Service it errors out.

URL of service on my machine:

```
   https://8KZVJS1/HeaderIntercept/HeaderIntercept.svc
```

When I try to submit a message I start getting errors:

**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**

I tried modifying my app.config but then now I only get:

**The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via**

update: Did some edits and I now get:
**There was no endpoint listening at `https://8kzvjs1/headerintercept/HeaderIntercept.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.**

I'm needing to get this working through a simple .NET client, then push it so we can use an Apache reverse proxy to pass on raw SOAP messages to it.

Any Thoughts?

Windows 7 - 64bit.

### **IIS**

SSL - Not required, but accepted

Anonymous Access - Enabled.

Configuration Editor - system.webServer/security/access SSl, SSLNegotiateCert, SSL128 checked

**WCF Web Service web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>        
    <bindings>    
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="HeaderIntercept">           
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WCFServiceCertificate.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
                      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
              <clientCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
              </clientCertificate>
              <serviceCertificate findValue="8KZVJS1" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  </system.webServer>
```

**Client app.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"  maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://8KZVJS1/HeaderIntercept/HeaderIntercept.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
          contract="HeaderIntercept.IHeaderIntercept" name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
        <identity>
          <dns value="8KZVJS1"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**IHeaderIntercept.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHeaderIntercept
{

    [OperationContract]
    XElement MCCI_IN200100BC(XElement xml);

}
```

**HeaderIntercept.svc**

```
namespace WCF_Header_Intercept
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class HeaderIntercept : IHeaderIntercept
    {
        public XElement MCCI_IN200100BC(XElement xml)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
            foreach (string key in headers.Keys) {
                sb.AppendLine("header " + key + "=" + headers[key]);
            }

            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.AsParallel().ForAll(h => sb.AppendFormat("Name={0}, IsReferenceParameter={1}, MustUnderstand={2}, Namespace={3}, Relay={4}, Actor={5}.{6}", h.Name, h.IsReferenceParameter, h.MustUnderstand, h.Namespace, h.Relay, h.Actor, Environment.NewLine));

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());
            return XElement.Parse("<data>" + sb.ToString() + "</data>");
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: [This might](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731362.aspx) be useful to you. By the way, your server config and your client config don't seem compatible because the client is using HTTPS (**transport** security) but the server isn't. Did you create the client config automatically (through **Add Service Reference**) or manually?

Comment: I'm kind of thinking that might be the case, as when I do it manually it's doing basicHttpBinding on the client, so I've done it manually. I'll check that out. Anything stand out to you?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I guess being polite isn't a requirement then John ;) Really, being appreciative, polite and honest about something is usually qualities we try to impart on people. Rather than be cold, technical and analytical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. My web.config binding was wrong when matching against my contracts. I removed the namespaces to make things a bit simpler, and got it to work.

Thanks Thomas for the insight. wish I could have marked that as an answer :\

**web.config:**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HeaderIntercept" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="IHeaderIntercept">
          <identity>
            <dns value="CGI-8KZVJS1"/>            
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**app.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHeaderIntercept" >
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
              <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://cgi-8kzvjs1/HeaderIntercept/HeaderIntercept.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHeaderIntercept"
            contract="HeaderIntercept.IHeaderIntercept" name="WSHttpBinding_IHeaderIntercept">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/CGI-8KZVJS1" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```